# MySQL: Exclude duplicate data

Tags: mysql

In one of my columns, there's are duplicates and I want to grab the first occurrence only. How can I do that? In the example, I want to grab all the rows that are unique in col C. So I only want `hello ladies`, `hello team`, `hello cats`, and `hello sexy`

```
Example Table
---------------

column A | col B | col C 
--------------------------
hello    | ladies| 1
hello    | guys  | 1
hello    | team  | 2
hello    | dogs  | 2
hello    | cats  | 3
hello    | cats  | 3
hello    | sexy  | 4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`DISTINCT`](http://www.sql-tutorial.com/sql-distinct-sql-tutorial/) keyword is not applicable in your case.

In the DB the order of rows is arbitrary.  You can however select just one of the B column for each unique C value using an aggregate function that can work with strings.  [MAX](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Oracle/0240__Aggregate-Functions/UseMAXwithstrings.htm) is such a function, if the 'maximum' of strings is an acceptable choice:

```
mysql> select A,max(B),C from Test group by C,A;
+-------+--------+------+
| A     | max(B) | C    |
+-------+--------+------+
| hello | ladies |    1 |
| hello | team   |    2 |
| hello | cats   |    3 |
| hello | sexy   |    4 |
+-------+--------+------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Wait, how would this work if I wanted to select all the columns? Wouldn't this mean I have to type out each one instead of using `*`? I tried this: `SELECT DISTINCT col C,* FROM table`

Answer (score 4):

Use the distinct() command.

```
select distinct(colc), cola, colb from table
```

This will only select the unique values

Answer (score 1):

With `LIMIT` you can get just one of something, if there are multiple of this thing. Also, if rows are completely identical, there is no way to distinguish them at all, so order does not matter.

```
SELECT * FROM t WHERE colc=3 LIMIT 1
```

Sometimes you want a report of rows that are duplicate:

```
SELECT colc, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM t GROUP BY colc
```

A GROUP BY clause looks at the fields that you name (here: `colc`) and considers all rows with the same colc value identical. It makes heaps for each `colc` value, so all `colc=1` go onto one heap, `colc=2` onto another and so on. The `COUNT()` aggregate function measures the height of these heaps.

A `HAVING` clause is a `WHERE`-like condition applied after the `GROUP BY`. We can use that to choose rows that are unique or that are duplicate, asking for `cnt` being 1 or larger than 1:

```
-- list all unique rows
SELECT colc, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM t GROUP BY colc HAVING cnt = 1
```

You can make the actual contents of the heaps visible:

```
SELECT colc, COUNT(*) as cnt, GROUP_CONCAT(colb) AS content FROM t GROUP BY colc HAVING cnt > 1
```

It is possible to delete all but one copy of duplicate rows using the MySQL extension of `LIMIT` with `DELETE`:

```
DELETE FROM t WHERE colc=3 LIMIT 1
```

This will match ALL `colc=3`, but will delete only one row due to the `LIMIT`.