# Removing duplicate results from MySQL query

Tags: mysql

I have two mysql tables Users & Messages. Please will you help me to create an sql query which returns only the most recent message either sent or received by the logged in user Mike ( user_id=1 ) along with the message_id, message_text & first_name of the person who the message was sent to or received from. Ordered by message_id in descending order.

So far i have the query:-

```
SELECT message_id, first_name, message_text FROM tbl_users, tbl_messages 
WHERE 
(tbl_users.user_id = tbl_messages.sender_id AND tbl_messages.receiver_id = 1 
OR tbl_users.user_id = tbl_messages.receiver_id AND tbl_messages.sender_id = 1) 
GROUP BY tbl_users.first_name
ORDER BY message_id DESC
```

Which gives the result in the image below. It seems the ORDER BY is being ignored

[image: Group by result]

Thank you in advance

tbl_users

```
---------------------------
| user_id |  first_name   |
---------------------------
| 1       |  Mike         |
| 2       |  John         |
| 3       |  George       |
| 4       |  Peter        |
| 5       |  Sarah        |
---------------------------
```

tbl_messages

```
----------------------------------------------------------------
| message_id |  sender_id   |  receiver_id   |  message_text   |
----------------------------------------------------------------
| 1          |  2           | 1              |  Hello          |
| 2          |  3           | 1              |  How are you    |
| 3          |  1           | 5              |  Hi there       |
| 4          |  2           | 1              |  Greetings      |
| 5          |  1           | 4              |  Good day       |
| 6          |  3           | 1              |  Hi             |
| 7          |  5           | 1              |  A message      |
| 8          |  5           | 4              |  Good morning   |
| 9          |  1           | 5              |  Hello dear     |
| 10         |  1           | 3              |  Howdy          |
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Desired result

```
----------------------------------------------
| message_id |  first_name  |  message_text  |
----------------------------------------------
| 10         |  George      | Howdy          |
| 9          |  Sarah       | Hello dear     |
| 5          |  Peter       | Good day       |
| 4          |  John        | Greetings      |
----------------------------------------------
```

Database is available [here](http://zimpeople.com/sample_db.sql)

Comment: do you mean recent message to or from person X? And result table doesn't tell has Mike sent or recieved message?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5510034/mysql-exclude-duplicate-data

Comment: Messages with id 10, 9 5 and 3 were sent by Mike to George, Sarah & Peter. Mike's name should never be in the results because he's the logged in user. It's like how the chat list is displayed on WhatsApp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>Just adding a `GROUP BY` clause may solve your problem, try this...</strike>

```
SELECT message_id, first_name, message_text FROM tbl_users, tbl_messages 
WHERE  
(tbl_users.user_id = tbl_messages.sender_id AND tbl_messages.receiver_id = 1 
OR tbl_users.user_id = tbl_messages.receiver_id AND tbl_messages.sender_id = 1) 
GROUP BY tbl_users.user_id
ORDER BY message_id DESC
```

**UPDATE: Changing the whole query**

```
SELECT t2.message_id, t2.first_name, t2.message_text FROM
(SELECT u.user_id, m.message_id, u.first_name, m.message_text FROM `tbl_users` u
  JOIN `tbl_messages` m ON (u.user_id = m.sender_id AND m.receiver_id = 1)
    OR (u.user_id = m.receiver_id AND m.sender_id = 1) 
  ORDER BY m.message_id DESC
) t2
GROUP BY t2.user_id
ORDER BY t2.message_id DESC
```

**RESULT:**

```
+------------+------------+--------------+
| message_id | first_name | message_text |
+------------+------------+--------------+
| 10         | George     | Howdy        |
| 9          | Sarah      | Hello dear   |
| 5          | Peter      | Good Day     |
| 4          | John       | Greetings    |
```

Comment: I'll modify the question to show the result when GROUP BY is added

Comment: Grouping by `tbl_users.first_name` gives the closest result just that the first 4 messages are returned instead of the last (most recent) 4. Grouping by multiple columns does not work

Comment: @user1715545 - I've updated my whole query and seems to be working fine... Sorry for the late reply...

Answer (score 2):

If you `GROUP BY` the field which you want to de-duplicate on. In this case `GROUP BY tbl_users.first_name` should do the trick.

Comment: What do you mean exactly? If you `GROUP BY tbl_users.first_name` it will show the unique first names. If you want to show unique values for all fields, you can `GROUP BY` multiple fields. Such as, `GROUP BY tbl_users.first_name, tbl_message.message_text`. This will show unique message/user entries.

Comment: Every field you want to be unique needs to be in the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Grouping by `tbl_users.first_name` gives the closest result just that the first 4 messages are returned instead of the last (most recent) 4. Grouping by multiple columns does not work

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you can achieve this through join. A sub select query may help you.

```
  select a.first_name, 
         (select message_text from tbl_messages b
          where (a.user_id = b.sender_id and b.sender_id = 1)
                or (a.user_id = b.receiver_id and b.receiver_id  = 1)
          order by message_id DESC
          LIMIT 1)
   from tbl_users a;
```

Comment: I'll try this and will let you know

Comment: I've tried to run the code exactly as you typed but i'm not getting any results

Comment: @user1715545 I made a mistake and put the filter on `user_id`. Updated the query. Please try and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the table name in the ORDER BY clause. Also I suggest using aliases on the tables. Thus, your query might look like this:

```
/* All Mike's messages */
SELECT
  m.message_id,
  u.first_name,
  m.message_text
FROM
  tbl_users AS u,
  tbl_messages AS m
WHERE  
(
  u.user_id = m.sender_id AND 
  m.receiver_id = 1
) OR (
  u.user_id = m.receiver_id AND 
  m.sender_id = 1
)
ORDER BY
  m.message_id DESC;
```

However, I think it would be better to get the sent and received messages results separately. So:

```
/* Messages sent my Mike */
SELECT
  m.message_id,
  u.first_name,
  m.message_text
FROM
  tbl_users AS u
  INNER JOIN tbl_messages AS m ON m.receiver_id = u.user_id
WHERE
  m.sender_id = 1
ORDER BY
  m.message_id DESC;

/* Messages received my Mike */
SELECT
  m.message_id,
  u.first_name,
  m.message_text
FROM
  tbl_users AS u
  INNER JOIN tbl_messages AS m ON u.user_id = m.sender_id
WHERE
  m.receiver_id = 1
ORDER BY
  m.message_id DESC;
```

Comment: I need the sent and received messages to be retrieved simultaneously so I can all list the conversations which Mike is involved in. Similar to the way chats are listed on WhatsApp. Aliases on table names are great, the result i get when i run your first query is exactly the same as the image in the question, even if i add `GROUP BY u.first_name` the first result should be message_id=10

Comment: I get "10 George Howdy" as my first result